# Convert from Excel datetime to ZonedDateTime

Tags: excel, java-time, zoneddatetime, excel-dates

A datetime in Excel is saved as the number of days since 1900-01-01 (+1 as it thinks 1900-02-29 occurred). The fraction in the number is the time offset in the day.

This number has no concept of timezones. So 12.5 is 1900-01-12T12:00:00 in the timezone you have your spreadsheet open in. Open it in Colorado and it shows noon. Open it in Germany and it shows noon. It's not an instant, it's a LocalDateTime.

For our system where we store everything as an OffsetDateTime or ZonedDateTime (depending on how the datetime was passed to us) the logical thing to do I think is create a ZonedDateTime from this.

Which leads to the question, how do I create a ZonedDateTime, set to this Excel datetime number, in the local time zone?

Comment: You could store the datetime as UDT perhaps in a hidden column and use a UDF that retrieves the time zone offset from individual machines' system regional settings to make the adjustment.

Comment: This may have some useful information https://superuser.com/questions/763996/how-does-the-now-function-get-evaluated-cross-time-zones-in-excel-online

Comment: If Excel saves its dates as the number of days since 1900-01-01 in datetime format without saving the time portion, that would be useless for datetime comparison functions where the time portion is required for exact computation e.g. in realtime systems, hospital applications, fintech business apps, etc. What if we need to extract from Excel to find the date difference between 2023-02-02 13:05:54 and 2022-01-01 09:33:25 (as shown in the Excel sheet) ? Extracting (from Excel) the values of 2023-02-02 00:00:00 and 2022-01-01 00:00:00 would definitely not be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    LocalDate msBaseDate = LocalDate.of(1899, Month.DECEMBER, 31);

    double dateFromExcel = 12.5;
    long nanosSinceBase = Math.round(dateFromExcel * TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos(1));
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = msBaseDate.atStartOfDay()
            .plusNanos(nanosSinceBase)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

On my computer the output is:

> 1900-01-12T12:00+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

Since java.time only uses whole numbers, I am used its finest granularity, nanoseconds. This will overflow a `long` in year 2192, so for a future-proof solution you may consider adding the whole days separately and only converting the fraction to nanos.